# Splitting lemma under assumption of the  axiom of choice

Tags: ct.category-theory, short-exact-sequences, axiom-of-choice

The [splitting lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) says:

> Given a short exact sequence with maps $q$ and $r$:
>
> $0 \rightarrow A \overset{q}{\rightarrow} B \overset{r}{\rightarrow} C \rightarrow 0$
>
> then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. there exists a map $u : C \rightarrow B$ such that $r \circ u = \mathrm{id}_C$
> 3. $B \cong A \oplus C$

Now I figured, since $r(B) = \ker 0$, $r$ is surjective. Hence, for every $c \in C$ we have some $b \in B$ such that $r(b) = c$. Simply set $u(c) = b$ for one of these $b$s and you have your map $u$.

However, it turns out that this construction assumes the axiom of choice; it chooses one element from each of an infinite number of sets. So my question is: assuming the axiom of choice, is condition (2) always satisfied? Because this would imply that (3) holds for any such short exact sequence. Or am I making some mistake here?

Comment: You aren't guaranteed that u is linear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are working in some fixed abelian category $\mathcal{A}$.

It is not true in general that every short exact sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ will split. The problem is that although you can pick a preimage for every 'element' $c\in C$ there is no guarantee that you can assemble this into a morphism in $\mathcal{A}$. It is true in the category of sets that every surjection splits if one assumes the axiom of choice but this is only a set map.

For instance in the category of abelian groups
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
is exact but $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is indecomposable.

Also if you are not in an abelian category it is not necessarily true that exact sequences display this symmetry. See for example [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3757/when-does-splits-imply-cosplits) question where the notion is considered in the category of groups.

Comment: So it should read "morphism" instead of "map" in the formulation of the lemma. My book (Miles Reid, Undergrad. Comm. Algebra) also calls it a "map". I'm not really familiar with category theory, but in algebraic geometry (homo)morphisms are always explicitly called so, and are not the same as maps in general. Hence the confusion; thank you all for the answers.

Comment: In category theory, "map" and "morphism" (and "arrow") are synonymous.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake you're making is that your map $u$ is not a homomorphism of (whatever $A$, $B$, $C$ are---possibly groups or modules), it's just going to be a map of sets, if you define it the way you defined it. Read the proof of the lemma to see why this isn't good enough. Or think of $Z/2Z$ living in $Z/4Z$ with quotient $Z/2Z$.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the axiom of choice is not required to prove the splitting lemma. I can see why you might think it might; I once came to the same conclusion myself. To split the sequence on the right, you could start by finding a section of the surjection, invoking AC. Then you can project out the part of your section which doesn't lie in the kernel, which ensures the map is a homomorphism.

I asked about for clarification on math.SE, with a negative answer: no choice necessary. Basically, instead of starting by splitting the surjection, you recall that a retraction of the injection was part of your given data, and use it to construct the splitting of the surjection, without making any arbitrary choices.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151438/does-the-splitting-lemma-hold-without-the-axiom-of-choice/

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of choice may give you a map $u:C\to B$ as SETS.  However, it may not be a morphism in the category of $R$-modules.

Answer (score 1):

This is right: a map $f:A \rightarrow B$ is surjectiv $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f$ has a right-inverse. The proof needs the axiom of choice, as you pointed out correctly. But this is just a map of sets.

EDIT: In the following I'm talking about groups (vector spaces, vector bundles, presheaves, sheaves,... should also do the job)

Every short exact seqeunce can be seen as a sequence
$$0 \overset{inc_0}\rightarrow A \overset{inc}{\rightarrow} B \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} B/A \rightarrow 0$$
where $inc$ denotes the inclusion and $\pi$ the projection.

But (as for example Charles Siegel pointed out) surjectivity gives you just a rightinverse $u:C \rightarrow B$ as map of sets. So if you have further structures (let's say a group structure, vector space structure, etc.), this doesn't mean, that the map $u$ is an inverse with respect to these structures

Answer (score 0):

It is not true: consider the exact sequence of abelian groups
$$0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{x\mapsto 3x} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{x\mapsto [x]_3} \mathbb{Z}/3 \longrightarrow 0 \quad$$ and note that the only homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is the zero one. So the sequence does not split.

EDIT - As clarification, in the splitting lemma, the third condition should be:

1. ...
2. ...
3. The sequence $0\rightarrow A \xrightarrow{q} B \xrightarrow{r} C\rightarrow 0$ and the canonical one $0\rightarrow A \xrightarrow{i} A \oplus C \xrightarrow{\pi} C\rightarrow 0$ are isomorphic (with the identities on A and on C).